# IReport - multiple grouping

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I need group data by 5 fields. It's ok, but I need show "Totals" in a new page after each first grouping.

Example:

Birth  Nationally      Car      Job     Name    Money
1980   North American  BMW      Doctor  Paul    $1200,0
1980   North American  BMW      Lawyer  Longman $2700,0
1980   North American  Mercedes Nurse   Lenna   $4200,0
1980   Canadian        Mercedes Police  John    $1300,0
1993   Italian         Ferrari  Pilot   Marco   $1500,0

I build my report in this way:
- Main report contain a subreport;
- Subreport (where the groups are):
Birth group header
     Nationally group header
          Car group header
              et...
          Car group footer
      Nationally group footer
Birth group footer (**here I put a SECOND SUBREPORT**, that need be in a new page)

- Second Subreport: contains the totals by birth, nationally and car, but only actual birth. After each Birth, I need show the sum of money. So, after 1980 would be shown:
  **1980**
   Nationally: North American    Car: BMW         **Total: $3.900**
   Nationally: North American    Car: Mercedes    **Total: $4.200**

In a first moment, my subreport 2 didnt work because has no data. So I copied the original data for each object (list X that contains list X). So the subreport 1 uses list X e and pass list X to subreport 2.
But I don't know how to filter the Birth in subreport 2.

Is my solution correct? If yes, how to solve the problem of subreport 2. If no, how should I build that?

Thanks in advance.